# Ember Cli Bootstrap Date Picker wrong format while using queryParam

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have been using `Ember-CLI-Bootstrap-Datepicker` for a while and I had no issue until now that when I am using `queryParams` to get Date Value for my search purpose the format in may params would be like :

```
"date_due_gteq=Thu%20Sep%2001%202016%2000%3A00%3A00%20GMT%2B0800%20(MYT)"
```

Which one is incorrect? I have searched and found that apparently my date object needs to be convert to `ToString` however, I have tried but still have the same problem.

that would be great if you guys have a an experience with this add-on, help me to figure it what is my mistake. I am sharing some part of the code :

Template :

```
{{bootstrap-datepicker value=date_due_gteq format="yyyy-mm-dd" placeholder="due date (to)" class="form-control" autoclose=true forceDateValue=true}}
```

Controller:

```
  queryParams: [ "date_due_gteq","date_due_lteq"],
  date_due_gteq: null,
  date_due_lteq: null,
```

Routes:

```
  model(params) {
    return this.findPaged('task', {
      q: {
        date_due_gteq: params.date_due_gteq,
        date_due_lteq: params.date_due_lteq,
      }
    });
  },
  actions: {
    queryChanged() {
      this.refresh();
    }
  }
```

this is possible solution from here https://github.com/soulim/ember-cli-bootstrap-datepicker/issues/72

> Hey @stonetwig! Because you have a Date object, it's up to you how to
>   transform it into string of any format.
>
> Example:
>
> var today = new Date(); today.toISOString(); // =>
>   "2016-03-04T09:20:49.447Z" Using other methods of Date object you
>   could extract year, day, hours, and etc.
>
> Query param could be bound to a Date object not directly, so then you
>   have freedom to transform it into string of required format, and also
>   convert a string of query param into a Date object.

Comment: I have solved myself and sent the solution below as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer for those who have this issue, I have fixed myself.

In your controller simply add a new property `startDateToJSDate` which will convert your date to a proper formatting with Moment or maybe you can do whatever else you want using `Ember.computed`

```
date_due_gteq: null,
startDateToJSDate: Ember.computed('date_due_gteq', {
    get(key) {
      return this.get('date_due_gteq') ? moment(this.get('date_due_gteq')).toDate() : null;
    },
    set(key, value) {
      this.set('date_due_gteq', value ? moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD') : '');
      return value;
    }
  }),
```

then change your datepicker input to

{{bootstrap-datepicker value=**startDateToJSDate** format="yyyy-mm-dd" placeholder="due date (from)" class="form-control" autoclose=true forceDateValue=true}}

In Addition, you can simply add your queryParam to replace your route or refresh your model

```
queryParams: {
    date_due_gteq: { replace: true },
  },
```

or

```
  queryParams: {
        date_due_gteq: { refreshModel: true },
      },
```

that's it. Now your Url will be like `tasks?date_due_gteq=2016-09-01`

I had a struggling time for this issue however I have fixed it myself and I would like to share it with you. Hope you can find this helpful.