# bootstrap datepicker format changes automatically on select textbox

Tags: jquery, ember.js, bootstrap-datepicker

I have used format `mm/yyyy` for date picker in ember as following:

```
$('#fromdatetimepicker').datetimepicker({

    format: 'MM/YYYY',
    showClose: true,
    showClear: true,
    keepOpen: false,
    sideBySide: true,
    maxDate: maxDate
});
```

but after clicking on date textbox for the second time, the format changes to `mm/dd/yyyy` automatically. pls help me to resolve it

Comment: @Power ember-2.6.0

Comment: show your entire component code if possible..may be try [twiddle](http://ember-twiddle.com)

Comment: I think it's similar to my problem previously, have a look at this , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39326582/ember-cli-bootstrap-date-picker-wrong-format-while-using-queryparam

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [ember-pikaday](https://github.com/edgycircle/ember-pikaday) for this, since it offers functions like `onSelection` where you can further manipulate your data.

E.g.:

```
// template
{{pikaday-input onSelection=(action 'selectDate') class="input" placeholder="Select date" format="MM/DD/YYYY"}}

// controller or component js
...
actions: {
    selectDate(date) {
        // do some further handling
        this.set('date', date);
    },
}
...
```